# PyCharm: limit cache size

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

When I search for this online, all I get are hits for increasing the cache size. According to `ncdu`, my PyCharm cache is 55GB. How can I prevent this from *ever* happening again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to limit caches, use File | Invalidate cache to clear them manually

Comment: I take the silence of others to suggest this is true. Will change my answer if someone provides a way to do this.